# How to update UITableView after adding/ updating data

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitableview

I am newbie for iPhone application. For storing data, I am following [`this tutorial`](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/).

I understand how to save data and retrieve the same.

What I am wanted to do is instead of another `UITableViewController` (first screen in storyboard, where we have list), I will drag a `UITableView` and show list of items there instead of showing in another screen.

Any idea/ suggestion how to get this done?

Any hints would be greatfull.

What I feel is, I would need to add `UITableView`. Add delegate and dataSource method on it and add a method where I will have all data shown in `UITableView`.

---

### Edit 1

What I want is **ONLY ONE SCREEN**. In the link that I have provided, it is second screen.

Comment: @dasdom : This will be case if I have two screens as shown in tutorial.

Comment: I don't understand WHY DOWNVOTE. I googled it, but didn't find a single example of what I wanted...

Comment: NO.. just that answer is not correct. I said I have used what is there in link.. so to get UIViewTable in another screen, I also have to copy paste the table methods. I now make it working... NO UNDERSTAND ACTUALLY UNDERSTAND MY PROBLEM.

Comment: actually I have the impression, that everybody understands you (you want to reuse the same table view without any form of drilling down) — it is you, who is too stubborn to realize how easy your problem can be solved.

Comment: and btw: making use reading up some tutorial to understand your question worth any down vote. it is common sense and written down in the faqs that question must be written in a way that they can be answered immediately without navigating to some other site. with your reputation you should know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine. But make sure you also have done a

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

after you've changed the data in your table view data source delegate.

Comment: I think you didn't see the link... This is general answer, however in my case this is not answer. Could you please explain, how this will help me?

Comment: this answers it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`What I am wanted to do is instead of another UITableViewController (first screen in storyboard, where we have list), I will drag a UITableView and show list of items there instead of showing in another screen.`

Why you want to do this way?

UX will not be  at best.

`What I feel is, I would need to add UITableView. Add delegate and dataSource method on it and add a method where I will have all data shown in UITableView.`

Even if you want to do, yes you need to set delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: I want to do that way because, I don't want user to navigate from the main screen. Let the user be on same screen...

Comment: I know I would need to add delegate and dataSource. I did it, but I am not getting, how I will call data in UITableView

Comment: check using break point that your datasource is getting called or not. And I hope your File's Owner and controller classes would be set properly.

Comment: I am not getting anything. Can you provide me little discription on how to get this done?

Comment: First thing you check in the controller class, where your tableview datasource is there, mark a break point and check if that code gets executed. Or before return [array count], use NSLog(@"in the datasource");